# Закрытие модального окна в компоненте React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Практикую React, столкнулся с проблемой. Когда модальное окно активно(компонента LoginForm) при клике за его пределами, нужно закрывать. Подскажите как на реализовать на примере.

```
export default () => {
    const cn = useClassName('home-page');
    const slider = useRef();
    const dataSet = [
    data
    ];

    const onNext = () => slider.current.next();

    const [active, setActive] = useState(false);
    const onStart = () => {
        setActive(true);
    };
    // const closeModal = (e) => {
    //     if (active) {
    //         setActive(!active);
    //     }
    // };



    return (
        <div className={cn()}>
            <Carousel dotsClass="test-className" ref={slider} effect="fade">
                {dataSet.map(elem =>
                    <Slider title={elem.title} img={elem.image} onNext={onNext} onStart={onStart} key={elem.index}/>
                )}
            </Carousel>

            <LoginForm style={active ? {display: 'block'} : {display: 'none'}} />
        </div>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Как один из быстрых вариантов.
Когда открывается модальное окно добавлять ещё и оверлей со стилями:

```
.overlay{
    background: rgba(0,0,0, 0.45);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

внутри этого блока размещаем модалку, `z-index:12;`
и вот пример кода:

```
<div class="overlay" onClick={(e) => setActive(false);}>
    <LoginForm style={active ? {display: 'block'} : {display: 'none'}} />
</div>
```